# Web pages in a webview how to obtain position

Tags: html, webview

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private WebView webView;`  

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);  
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);    
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        String appCachePath = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
        webSettings.setAppCachePath(appCachePath);
        webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);  
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        @Override
        public void onReceivedIcon(WebView view, Bitmap icon) {
            super.onReceivedIcon(view, icon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsHidePrompt() {
            super.onGeolocationPermissionsHidePrompt();
        }
    });

    /* 
     * setWebViewClient()
     * shouldOverrideUrlLoading
     * */  
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){  

        @Override  
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }  
    });  
    webView.loadUrl("http://uri.amap.com/line");   
}
```

I write a map page in webview. This is a **HTML** page.

But can't locate.Unable to display. I want the webview positioning can be obtained.In the system browser can show the location.This is I write my own code, I don't know how to do